# How to get score for all classes when using YOLO v3?

Tags: yolo, darknet, darkflow

How do I get scores for all classes? For example, there is a dog object, with score 0.9. However I also want the cat score for the same object (0.1). How do I get them?

Comment: Is it about YOLO or YOLOv3?

Comment: @FelixKleineBösing it's about YOLOv3

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get an object in picture by YOLOv3, YOLOv3 give you array that is composed of bounding box coordinate and every class score.

For example, in COCO dataset, they have 80 objects such as dog(17th class), cat(16th class), etc.

An array would keep all object's score, but you can't get all score in usually because open-source code give you only best-scored object.

Just check part of your code before returning best-scored object result.

You will find all object scores in there.